# Python OpenCV Opening Vid File vs. Opening Webcam

Tags: python, opencv

I cant figure out why this is not working.

The following code works perfectly using my webcam:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
# Define the codec and create VideoWriter object
fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'XVID')
out = cv2.VideoWriter('output.avi',fourcc, 20.0, (640,480))
while(cap.isOpened()):
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    if ret==True:
        frame = cv2.flip(frame,0)
        # write the flipped frame
        out.write(frame)
        cv2.imshow('frame',frame)
        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break
    else:
        break
# Release everything if job is finished
cap.release()
out.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Yet when I exchange the Webcam for a video file, the output does not generate a video. Only a 5.7kb file named output.avi:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
cap = cv2.VideoCapture('Input.avi')
# Define the codec and create VideoWriter object
fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'XVID')
out = cv2.VideoWriter('output.avi',fourcc, 20.0, (640,480))
while(cap.isOpened()):
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    if ret==True:
        frame = cv2.flip(frame,0)
        # write the flipped frame
        out.write(frame)
        cv2.imshow('frame',frame)
        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break
    else:
        break
# Release everything if job is finished
cap.release()
out.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I can see in my windows that the video is being processed but is not being saved. I have also tried changing the resolution to match the initial video file.

Comment: what happens if you comment out the while-loop completely, thus effectively only opening and closing output.avi?

Answer (score 0):

I'm using OpenCV on Ubuntu, and this worked for me:

```
out = cv2.VideoWriter("output.avi", cv.CV_FOURCC(*'DIVX'), fps, (640, 480))
```

See if it works on Windows.